# Custom header in each page of LightSwitch

Tags: header, visual-studio-lightswitch

Can someone help me in adding a custom image/header (a html file containing titles, images and links) in each page of LightSwitch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by loading an HTML file as a fixed header as shown below in the `default.htm` file,

Before,

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            msls._run()
            .then(null, function failure(error) {
                alert(error);
            });
        });
   </script>
```

After,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.get("PartialViews/header.htm", function (response) {
                var logfile = response;
                document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin", logfile);
                msls._run()
                .then(null, function failure(error) {
                    alert(error);
                });
            });
        });
 </script>
```

The `header.htm` file contains the fixed titles, images and links.